# Showing/hiding elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

having a little trouble here when trying to show or hide divs in react.

I have three classes:

```
1. RunningOrder Section
2. RunningOrder
3. Story
```

running order section is the main section, which renders the running order class, and running order renders the Story class.

I have a toggle switch in running order section which toggles the 'displayStory' state in running order and running order passes the 'displayStory' bool state as a prop to story.

toggle in RunningOrder Section:

```
_triggerChildDisplay: function () {
  this.refs.child.displayStory();
},

<Toggle
  tooltip = {'Auto Sequence'}
  onToggle = {this._triggerChildDisplay}
/>

for (let storyId in ro.stories) {
        allStories.push(<Story key={storyId} story={ro.stories[storyId]} displayStory={this.state.displayStory}/>)
    };
```

state and prop in Running Order:

```
displayStory: function() {
   this.setState({
      displayStory: !this.state.displayStory
   });
},

for (let storyId in ro.stories) {
   allStories.push(<Story key={storyId} story={ro.stories[storyId]} displayStory={this.state.displayStory}/>)
};
```

render method of story

```
   if(allItems.length > 0) {
            return (
                <div className="story-container"> 
                    <div className="story-label-container">
                        <div className="story-slug">

                            <span className="story-title">
                                {story.slug}
                            </span>

                            {/*<span className="storyItemLength">
                                {allItems.length}
                            </span>*/}

                            <span className="story-sequence-control">
                                <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={autoSequenceTooltip}>
                                    <Toggle
                                        label = {<SequenceIcon />}
                                        disabled = {allItems.length > 0? false : true}
                                        tooltip = {'Auto Sequence'}
                                        onToggle = {this.toggled}
                                    />
                                </OverlayTrigger>

                            </span>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    {itemList}

                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div className={this.props.displayStory ? "story-container" : "hidden story-container"}>                
                    <div className="story-label-container">
                        <div className="story-slug">

                            <span className="story-title">
                                {story.slug}
                            </span>

                            {/*<span className="storyItemLength">
                                {allItems.length}
                            </span>*/}

                            <span className="story-sequence-control">
                                <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={autoSequenceTooltip}>
                                    <Toggle
                                        label = {<SequenceIcon />}
                                        disabled = {allItems.length > 0? false : true}
                                        tooltip = {'Auto Sequence'}
                                        onToggle = {this.toggled}
                                    />
                                </OverlayTrigger>

                            </span>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    {itemList}
                </div>
            );
        }

    }
```

I only want to be able to toggle the display of elements in story if the allItems array has length greater than 0, hence the two returns.

Running order loops and pulls data from a server, the running order class returns 3 items each of these items have multiple items in them rendered by story which i need to toggle the display of.

Now my code is working, but for some reason I can only toggle the display (the hidden css class) in the last element returned by running order. so if running order returned:

```
<div 1>
   <items />
</div>
<div 2>
   <items />
</div>
<div 3>
   <items />
</div>
```

the display toggle only affects the items in div 3.

*******Update:** instead of a single toggle for all elements rendered by running order I have put the toggle switch in running order and it works fine, so it is something with call the reffs here: `this.refs.child.displayStory();`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w4q5mwvw/1/

hope this fiddle helps you

Comment: Thanks for the info, But I know how to show and hide elements and as mentioned in the post I am already showing and hiding elements. It just only seems to affect the last item rendered by runningOrder